# RC car to robot

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I am trying to build an RC car in Arduino which has a sensor so it doesn't hit walls.

My code seems to be working but every time it gets close to a wall and tries to back up it doesn't go far back enough and keeps ramming into the same wall.

```
// this constant won't change.  It's the pin number
// of the sensor's output:
const int pingPin = 7;
int echoPin=2;

// distance variables
long duration; // variable for duration sound travel
int distance; // variable for distance measurement


void setup() {


  // initialize serial communication:
  Serial.begin(9600);
 
  pinMode(pingPin, OUTPUT); // Sets the trigPin as an OUTPUT
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);


 
  //establish motor direction toggle pins
  pinMode(12, OUTPUT); //drive motor -- HIGH = forwards and LOW = backwards
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT); //turn motor -- HIGH = left and LOW = right
 
  pinMode(pingPin, OUTPUT); // Sets the trigPin as an OUTPUT
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);

  //establish motor brake pins
  pinMode(9, OUTPUT); //brake (disable) the drive motor
  pinMode(8, OUTPUT); //brake (disable) the turn motor


  //Turns brake off for drive motor
  digitalWrite(9, LOW);

  //Turns brake on for turn motor
  digitalWrite(8, HIGH);

  //Sets initial speed of drive motor
  analogWrite(3, 200);
 
  //Sets initial direction of drive motor
  digitalWrite(12, HIGH);
}

void loop()
{
  // establish variables for duration of the ping,
  // and the distance result in inches and centimeters:
  long duration, inches, cm;

  // The PING))) is triggered by a HIGH pulse of 2 or more microseconds.
  // Give a short LOW pulse beforehand to ensure a clean HIGH pulse:
  pinMode(pingPin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(pingPin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(pingPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(5);
  digitalWrite(pingPin, LOW);

  // The same pin is used to read the signal from the PING))): a HIGH
  // pulse whose duration is the time (in microseconds) from the sending
  // of the ping to the reception of its echo off of an object.

  duration = pulseIn(pingPin, HIGH);

  // convert the time into a distance
  inches = microsecondsToInches(duration);


      // Clears the trigPin condition
  digitalWrite(pingPin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  // Sets the pingPin HIGH (ACTIVE) for 10 microseconds
  digitalWrite(pingPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(pingPin, LOW);
  // Reads the echoPin, returns the sound wave travel time in microseconds
  duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
  // Calculating the distance
  distance = duration * 0.034 / 2; // Speed of sound wave divided by 2 (go and back)
  // Displays the distance on the Serial Monitor
  Serial.print("Distance: ");
  Serial.print(distance);
  Serial.println("cm");

  // convert the time into a distance
  inches = microsecondsToInches(duration);
\
//tell it to send the measurements to the serial monitor
  Serial.print(inches);
  Serial.print("in, ");
  Serial.print(cm);


 
  if (inches < 12 ){
   
    //brake drive motor and pause 1/10 second


    //
    //setting turn motor
    //
   
    //turn off brake for turn motor
    digitalWrite(8, LOW);

    //set turn motor direction
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);

    //activate turn motor
    analogWrite(11, 255);
   
    //
    //setting drive motor
    //
   
    //turn off brake of drive motor
    digitalWrite(9, LOW);
   
    //set drive motor backwards direction
    digitalWrite(12, LOW);
   
    //activate the drive motor
    analogWrite(3, 200);

   
    //backup for 2 seconds
    delay(2000);
   
    //
    //stopping
    //
   
    //brake both motors
    digitalWrite(8, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(9, HIGH);

   

   
  }
 
  //
  //when nothing is within 12"
  //the robot simply drives forwards
  //
 
  else{
   
    //
    //Setting drive motor
    //
   
    //set drive motor forward direction
    digitalWrite(12, HIGH);
   
    //turn off brake of drive motor
    digitalWrite(9, LOW); 

    digitalWrite(8, HIGH);
   
    //activate drive motor
    analogWrite(3, 200);
 
 
  }
 
  delay(100);
}


long microsecondsToInches(long microseconds)
{
  return microseconds / 74 / 2;
}
```

I have tried to take out my pins from the motor shield and actually putting it into the pins but that did nothing. I also gave it a new battery for more power but nothing has changed.

It turns left since pin 13 when `HIGH` is left (`HIGH` = left, `LOW` = right). I tried to change the delay but it goes forward for like 2 seconds then stops for no reason.

The code is from [Instructables - RC car to Robot](https://www.instructables.com/RC-Car-to-Robot/). I also changed  the code from a 3 pin sensor to a 4pin.

Comment: Increase the delay for the backup?

Comment: Also after backing up,  does your car move left or right (for say 45° or 90°) to change direction in order to avoid hitting the wall again?

Comment: It turns left since 13,High is left High = left low = right

Comment: I tried to change the delay but it goes forward for like 2 seconds than stops for no reason

Comment: Ah ok, in that case, please [edit] your question and add that information to your question. Any additional details should be placed in the question post and **not** in the comments. Maybe also describe iin greater detail what the car does when it backs up. Does it just backup in a straight line, or does it turn whilst backing up? What is is supposed to do, and what does it actually do? The more details you provide the easier it would be to answer the question. Don't forget we don't have your car so we can't test any suggested code changes.

Comment: I also changed the the code from a 3 pin sensor to a 4pin

Comment: I see, this is [the link](https://www.instructables.com/RC-Car-to-Robot/) that you used.  This maybe useful for you [Elegoo Smart Car Tutorial](https://toptechboy.com/category/elegoo-smart-car-tutorial/). Lessons 16, 17, 18 deal with the SR-04 and lesson 18 has obstacle avoidance code.  I recommend starting at the beginning: [Robotics Training LESSON 1: An Introduction to Robotics for Absolute Beginners](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eqXQ80vlgqE). Watch the videos, the guy is a good tutor... they might teach you write better code and understand it more deeply..  Good luck... :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the code on the Instructables website, [RC car to Robot](https://www.instructables.com/RC-Car-to-Robot/), when an obstacle is encountered, then the car should reverse *to the right*, as shown in this bit of the code:

```
  if (inches < 12 ){
   
    //brake drive motor and pause 1/10 second


    //
    //setting turn motor
    //
   
    //turn off brake for turn motor
    digitalWrite(8, LOW);

    //set turn motor direction
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);

    //activate turn motor
    analogWrite(11, 255);

    ...
```

If it is not reversing far enough, then increase the delay used during the reverse, from 2000 to 4000:

```
    //backup for 4 seconds
    delay(4000);
```

If it is reversing straight, *without turning*, then there is clearly a problem with the steering.

If that is the case, then I would suggest writing some other code that just checks the steering first: A sketch that simply drives the car in a circle. For example, first anti-clockwise, i.e. steering left (`digitalWrite(13, HIGH);`), and then clockwise, i.e. steering right (`digitalWrite(13, LOW);`)

---

#### Error in code?

Actually, you seem to be missing a couple of lines in your code, when compared to the code on the Instructables page. These lines are missing

```
    digitalWrite(9, HIGH);
    delay(100);
```

In the `if` dealing with the obstacle detection, you have:

```
  if (inches < 12 ){

    //brake drive motor and pause 1/10 second


    //
    //setting turn motor
    //

    ...
```

but it should be

```
  if (inches < 12 ){

    //brake drive motor and pause 1/10 second
    digitalWrite(9, HIGH);
    delay(100);

    //
    //setting turn motor
    //

    ...
```

This *may* be the cause of your problem.

---

#### Further reading

- [Controlling a DC Motor with Motor Shield Rev3](https://docs.arduino.cc/tutorials/motor-shield-rev3/msr3-controlling-dc-motor)